# selenium python for loop printing only first element repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get business info from this [page](https://www.yell.com/s/sliding+doors-dh1.html).

Here I am selecting the main container for each item then using for loop for getting business title from each container.

Here is my code:

```
container = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".businessCapsule--mainRow")
for i in container:
    business_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-h2')
    print(business_title)
```

result:

```
Mirror & Glass Processing Ltd
Mirror & Glass Processing Ltd
Mirror & Glass Processing Ltd
Mirror & Glass Processing Ltd
```

**Why It's printing only first item repeatedly?** Where I am doing mistake in my above code.

If I tried without selecting main container then it's working.

```
business_title = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text-h2")
for i in business_title:
        business_title = i.text
        print(business_title)
```

result:

```
Mirror & Glass Processing Ltd
J.E.D Double Glazing Repairs
B & R Glazing Co.Ltd
Durham Window & Door Centre Ltd
Ken Rose Joinery & Glazing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the for loop code block you have to use `i` instead of `driver`

```
business_title = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-h2')
```