# Python Selenium lists only one li repeatedly

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to make an attendance app, using Selenium; the script should read the names and click on a designated checkbox when a name is matched. What happens is that it keeps clicking on the first checkbox repeatedly. When I looked into it turns out that it only reads the first li only.
here's the HTML code

```
 <div class="members">
  <ul class="memberlist"></ul>
</div>
```

the li are generated via fetch API from the database
when I try these in python, it only reads the first li element over and over

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//ul[@class='memberlist']/li/p").text)

for i in range(len(df)):
    print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"name").text)
```

also, I tried the solution from this and I don't think this is the correct syntax
[selenium python for loop printing only first element repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120387/selenium-python-for-loop-printing-only-first-element-repeatedly)

Update: as per dosas comment, this did list all the names instead of just one, then I wrote this to click on the checkboxes of the attendees.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    # match names of the sheet with the 'name' class in the webpage
    if df['name'][i]==driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"name")[i].text:
        driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, week)[i].click()
        print(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"name")[i].text)
    else:
        print('No match')
```

Now I have a different problem, the attendance excel sheet has to be in the same order as the list on the web page, otherwise, it'll show 'No match'. So how do I make it search the whole page for each particular name?

Comment: Can you supply an URL?

Comment: I think you should be using `find_elements` and loop over the result?